# Android Emulator to be writable

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, qemu

I have downloaded the AOSP source code and build it. I launched the emulator and it works fine. Now I can't create any directories( adb root adb shell) as it throws an exception "read-only system". when i launch emulator using "emulator writable-system" it still doesn't allow me to create any directories unless I execute the command "adb remount". Is it possible to make the image writable.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ emulator -list-avds
$ emulator -avd $name_of_your_avd -writable-system
$ adb root
$ adb remount
```

that's how you make the image writable.
what are you trying to achieve?